# how to render arraylist or list and to handle it in template play framework 2.x

Tags: playframework-2.0, template-engine

I was familiar with `Play 1.x`. But I had to use `cassandra` DB. That is why I had to use `Play  2.x`

However Scala mixing everything really. Template is very different in `Play 2.x` For example, in `Play 1.x` I just could send any parameter as `String`, `int`, `object` instance, `arraylist` etc.

In render to the view template and could use these paramaters easly in template. I dont know how to succed this in `Play 2.x` there is only a render and it just enable me to render a `String`.

I read something about this in `Play 2.x` document. Could you please show me some examples or point me some tutorials about that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `Play 2.x` every view is compiled to the Scala function, so for `security`, `performance` and `compilation` reasons means that you **must** to declare arguments (and their types) in the views and fortunately it can be any type you wish (not only `String`).

For an example if you have model `model.Book` and want to pass a `List` of `model.Book` to the view, you need to declare it in the first line of the `view`:

`/app/controllers/Application.java`:

```
public static Result listAllBooks(){
    List<Book> books = Book.find.all();
    return ok(listAllBooksView.render(books));
}
```

`/app/views/listAllBooksView.scala.html`

```
@(books: List[Book])

@for(book <- books){
    @book.title <br>
}
```

Comment: thanks again biesior. Since I didn't have scala plugin in my eclipse, it always shows me error and asks me the parameter in render should be String, actually this was not error :)

Comment: consider using IntelliJ - Idea 12. it's paid, however does its work and you can try it before buy