# Template Displaying Model Path before Value

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, one-to-many, ebean

Data below is model deign of Doctor User Accounts which has @OneToMany relationship established with Appointments

```
@Id
public Long id;
@Lob
public String firstname;
@Lob
public String lastname;
@Lob
public String email;
@Lob
public String password;
@OneToMany(mappedBy="doctorid", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
public List<DoctorAppointment> doctorappointments;
```

Doctor Appointment model deign

```
@Id
public Long id;
@Lob
public String date;
@Lob
public String time;
@Lob
public String specialization;
@ManyToOne
public DoctorUserAccounts doctorid;
```

I was successful in fetching record too with code below

```
DoctorAppointment.find.fetch("doctorid").where().eq("patientid_id", patientid).orderBy("Date").findList();
```

My Problem is when I try to render the list on to my template from DoctorAppointment

```
Appointment ID  Date    Time    Specialization  Doctor ID
6   08/04/2018  10:15 AM    Obstetrician    models.DoctorUserAccounts@2
7   08/04/2018  11:45 AM    Gynecologist    models.DoctorUserAccounts@1
8   08/04/2018  11:45 AM    Gynecologist    models.DoctorUserAccounts@1
9   09/04/2018  11:45 AM    Gynecologist    models.DoctorUserAccounts@1
```

In column Doctor ID the Model Path is getting rendered "models.DoctorUserAccounts@2" how can I remove that tag.
Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Why are using @Lob for all fields? Anyway, try to add a `@JoinColumn` to your `@ManyToOne` side, and share how you're calling the object in your template.

Comment: Passing parameter to Template @(appointments: List[DoctorAppointment]).  "Why are using @Lob for all fields?" sorry for that, I am very much new to environment.

Comment: Can you suggest me what should be there in place of '@Lob'?

Comment: Changed '@Lob' to '@Column(name=" ")' and also added '@JoinColumn' still render with same problem... @Luay Abdulraheem

Comment: The name property in `@Column` annotation must match your DB column name so don't leave it empty, and for rendering have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14715962/how-to-render-arraylist-or-list-and-to-handle-it-in-template-play-framework-2-x?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: I've followed the same method which is in the link. @Luay Abdulraheem